# mapping two points on image to another one

Tags: java, javafx, geometry, javafx-8

I am trying to map two points on  one image to two points on the original image so i divided the work into three main actions first scaling the n rotation then translation after everything but cant position them correctly the scaling works fine and the translation also the rotation works perfectly if i didn't scale the images only way the rotation work perfectly when i rotate around custom point but the image get distorted

```
        Rotate rotation = new Rotate();
        rotation.setPivotX(proj.s2[0]);
        rotation.setPivotY(proj.s2[1]);
        MainView1.getTransforms().add(rotation);
        MainView1.setManaged(false);
        rotation.setAngle(Angle);
```

[image: original image][image: second image]
here is the code without custom rotation

```
guidebutton.setOnMouseClicked(event->{
        if (!first_rot) {
            proj.f2[0]=Lball.getCenterX();
            proj.f2[1]= Lball.getCenterY();
            proj.f1[0]=Rball.getCenterX();
            proj.f1[1]= Rball.getCenterY();
            MainView.setStyle("-fx-opacity  : 0.0;");
            guidetext.setText("now position them on the second image and click done");
            first_rot=true;
        }else {
            proj.s2[0]=Lball.getCenterX();
            proj.s2[1]= Lball.getCenterY();
            proj.s1[0]=Rball.getCenterX();
            proj.s1[1]= Rball.getCenterY();
            //fixing the image first then fixing the points
            // fixing the image
            //adjusting the scale 
            double f[]=tranformations.dis_vec_d(proj.f1, proj.f2);//get the distance between the two points on the first image
            double s[]=tranformations.dis_vec_d(proj.s1, proj.s2);//get the distance between the two points on the secondimage
            double facx=f[0]/s[0];//factor of scale in x direction
            double facy=f[1]/s[1];//factor of scale in y direction
            //getting the position of second image inside the window
            Bounds bounds = MainView1.getBoundsInLocal();
            Bounds screenBounds = MainView1.localToScreen(bounds);
            double x = screenBounds.getMinX();
            double y =  screenBounds.getMinY();

           MainView1.setScaleX(facx);
           // get the new position of image after scaling to adjust the position

            bounds = MainView1.getBoundsInLocal();
            screenBounds = MainView1.localToScreen(bounds);
            double nx = screenBounds.getMinX();
            double ny =  screenBounds.getMinY();
            double nmx = screenBounds.getMaxX()-nx;
            double nmy =  screenBounds.getMaxY()-ny;
            MainView1.setTranslateX(x-nx);
            MainView1.setTranslateY(y-ny);
            double[]orig={nmx/2,nmy/2};


            //adjusting rotation
              //calculating the angle between the two line to adjust the rotation
            double Angle=tranformations.angle_d(proj.s1, proj.s2);
            Angle-=tranformations.angle_d(proj.f1, proj.f2);
            //Add the Rotate to the ImageView's Transforms
            MainView1.setRotate(Angle);
            MainView1.setTranslateX(MainView.getTranslateX()+proj.f2[0]-proj.s2[0]);
            MainView1.setTranslateY(MainView.getTranslateY()+proj.f2[1]-proj.s2[1]);

        }
    });
```

both views and points in unmanaged group "draw" when i get every thing work it get down when i use zooming when positioning points on the second image
i use this code for zooming using mouse  wheel

```
    final double SCALE_DELTA = 1.1;
    draw.setOnScroll(event->{
        event.consume();

        if (event.getDeltaY() == 0) {
          return;
        }

        double scaleFactor =(event.getDeltaY() > 0)? SCALE_DELTA: 1/SCALE_DELTA;

        draw.setScaleX(draw.getScaleX() * scaleFactor);
        draw.setScaleY(draw.getScaleY() * scaleFactor);

    });
```

edit to explain the question more i have these two separate images and i use the two red points on lights as to correctly position them over each other to so they can form the new image complete image [image: top][image: bottom image]

[image: complete image]

Comment: I don't know if I truly understand your question or what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: i have two points on the original image and the same points on the morphed image i want to restore it to the original state using these two points as if i have two images of the same object and the two points are the common between the two images so i can restore the original object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First align one of the points using a translation then scale using the aligned point's coordinates as pivot and finally use the same pivot point to perform a rotation aligning the other points.

The following example uses groups containing 2 circles each, but it should be simple enough to replace `centerX`/`centerY` with the image coordinates of the points:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    // create group containing scene that remains in place
    Circle target1 = new Circle(100, 200, 20, Color.RED);
    Circle target2 = new Circle(150, 100, 20, Color.RED);
    Group targetGroup = new Group(target1, target2);

    // create group that will be transformed
    Circle c1 = new Circle(30, 30, 20, Color.BLUE);
    Circle c2 = new Circle(400, 400, 20, Color.BLUE);
    Group g = new Group(c1, c2);

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(targetGroup, g), 500, 500);

    // register handler for swapping between transformed/untransformed scene on button click
    scene.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {

        boolean transformed;
        final Translate translate = new Translate();
        final Scale scale = new Scale();
        final Rotate rotate = new Rotate();

        {
            // add transforms to transformation target            
            g.getTransforms().addAll(rotate, scale, translate);
        }

        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
            if (transformed) {
                // reset transforms to identity
                translate.setX(0);
                translate.setY(0);
                scale.setX(1);
                scale.setY(1);
                rotate.setAngle(0);
            } else {
                // align c1 and target1
                translate.setX(target1.getCenterX() - c1.getCenterX());
                translate.setY(target1.getCenterY() - c1.getCenterY());

                // scale
                double scaleFactor = Math.hypot(target1.getCenterX() - target2.getCenterX(), target1.getCenterY() - target2.getCenterY())
                        / Math.hypot(c1.getCenterX() - c2.getCenterX(), c1.getCenterY() - c2.getCenterY());
                scale.setPivotX(target1.getCenterX());
                scale.setPivotY(target1.getCenterY());
                scale.setX(scaleFactor);
                scale.setY(scaleFactor);

                // rotate
                rotate.setPivotX(target1.getCenterX());
                rotate.setPivotY(target1.getCenterY());
                rotate.setAngle(Math.toDegrees(Math.atan2(target2.getCenterY() - target1.getCenterY(), target2.getCenterX() - target1.getCenterX())
                        - Math.atan2(c2.getCenterY() - c1.getCenterY(), c2.getCenterX() - c1.getCenterX())));

            }
            transformed = !transformed;
        }
    });
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer the points get moved perfectly using you code but the image being mapped gets distorted @fabian

Comment: This is certainly not caused by the code I posted. Rotating, scaling by the same `x` and `y` factory and translation does not distort an image. This means there is either some error rewriting the code above, you apply a transformation somewhere else or the source image is distorted in the first place.

Comment: the second image is not the same scale as the first image that is only
at first i kept the image nside the same group and resized only the image then i tried to place it inside another group and resized it and got the same result

Comment: i am sorry the fault was mine i wasn't correctly positioning the points that lead to distortion of the image
thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This is particularly simple using complex numbers.

An arbitrary similarity transform can be written

```
Z = a.z + b
```

where the modulus of `a` is the scaling factor, the argument of `a` is the rotation angle and `b` is the translation.

These coefficients are readily obtained from the known pairs of points by the usual two-points interpolation formula

```
Z = Z0 + (z - z0).(Z1 - Z0)/(z1 - z0)
```

or

```
a = (Z1 - Z0)/(z1 - z0)
b = Z0 - a.z0
```

You have the option of using a complex data type, or to retranscript the formulas in terms of real/imaginary parts.

Answer (score 0):

If the square isn't rotated, then yeah, pick x and y independently.

If the square is rotated, the math gets a little trickier.  Let's let the two end points of the diagonal be X and Y, represented as complex numbers.

Then look at the equation:

```
(Y - X)/(1 + i) x + X
```

When x = 0, this returns X.  When x = 1 + i, it returns Y.  In fact, this equation maps the unit rectangle onto the square whose diagonal's endpoints are X and Y.

So pick two random numbers `0 ≤ a, b ≤ 1`, turn it into a random point `a + bi` on the unit rectangle, and then use the above equation to map into into a random point in the square.